# What's wrong with my Outlook search?

Tags: ms-office, spotlight

Ever since doing OS X 10.8 updates, a pair of machines with Outlook refuse to look back further than 2 weeks during e-mail searches.  Spotlight settings all look OK.  I even forced an index deletion/re-creation with "sudo mdutil -E".  Index does go away, but comes back the same way, only being able to search the last 2 weeks worth of items (and there are items going back years it should be finding).  Mailbox size is right around 1.9 GiB.  Ideas?

Comment: I see this happen somewhat often in our office environment where Outlook 2011 is connected to our Exchange server.  Typically a spotlight re-index will do the trick, either using the method you tried or by adding the HD to Spotlight's privacy pane, then removing it a few minutes later.  Sometimes I have to go a step further & remove preference files. spotlight.plist, outlook.plist, etc... Beyond that I will sometimes be forced to rebuild the Outlook identity using the Microsoft Database Utility (hold opt while opening Outlook).  Hope that helps!  (edit- Oddly it's always 2 weeks here as well)

Comment: @Mr Rabbit - Make that comment an answer and I'll accept it!  Outlook identity rebuild fixed it.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this happen somewhat often in our office environment where Outlook 2011 is connected to our Exchange server. Typically a spotlight re-index will do the trick, either using the method you tried or by adding the HD to Spotlight's privacy pane, then removing it a few minutes later. Sometimes I have to go a step further & remove preference files. spotlight.plist, outlook.plist, etc... Beyond that I will sometimes be forced to rebuild the Outlook identity using the Microsoft Database Utility (hold opt while opening Outlook). Hope that helps! (Oddly it's always 2 weeks here as well)